# How to make different shapes layouts

Tags: android, shapes

i am beginner level android developer and i know basics of layouts and views.Now i want to go one step ahead and want to learn interactive designs like this image 
https://ufile.io/uas4ljkr

In this image we have red area and white area and both are separated with a wave like shape not simple shape which we see in all layouts.Any help regarding this will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A good way of accomplishing this is to just to create your own custom view and override the `onDraw()` method.
https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing

I did simple quick and dirty custom drawing for you that is similar to example you gave

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var waveView: WaveView? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val wave = WaveView(this)
    waveView = wave

    setContentView(wave)
 }
}
```

WaveView

```
class WaveView @JvmOverloads constructor(
context: Context,
attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

private val paint = Paint()
private val path = Path()

init {
    paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
    paint.isAntiAlias = true
    paint.isDither = true
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    val point1X = width * 0.0f
    val point1Y = height * 0.5f

    val point2X = width * 0.35f
    val point2Y = height * 0.45f

    val point3X = width * 0.5f
    val point3Y = height * 0.3f

    val point4X = width * 0.75f
    val point4Y = height * 0.1f


    val point5Y = height * 0.25f

    paint.color = Color.RED
    canvas?.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
    path.moveTo(0f, 0f)
    path.lineTo(point1X, point1Y)
    path.quadTo(point2X, point2Y, point3X, point3Y)
    path.lineTo(width.toFloat(), point3Y)
    path.lineTo(width.toFloat(), 0f)
    canvas?.drawPath(path, paint)

    path.reset()
    paint.color = Color.WHITE

    path.moveTo(point3X, height.toFloat())
    path.lineTo(point3X, point3Y)
    path.quadTo(point4X, point4Y, width.toFloat(), point5Y)
    path.lineTo(width.toFloat(), height.toFloat())

    canvas?.drawPath(path, paint)
  }

}
```

[custom wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKQVM.png)

Hopefully this points you in the right direction.